# Php Script failing to continue after a for(;;) loop

Tags: php, wimp

I have a PHP script that queries a database and fills out some `<option>` tags inside a `<select>` tag. See code below:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($dbc, $tsql, $params, $dbcOptions);
if($stmt === false) {
        die ( print_r (sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
#echo $rows.'rows';
echo '<!--'.$rows.'-->';
echo '<select onchange="getNamesByDep(this.value)">';
echo '<option value="">Select a Department. . .</option>';

for ($i = 1; i <= $rows; $i++)
{
        if(sqlsrv_fetch($stmt) !== false)
        {
                $DepName = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt,0);
                echo '    <option row="'.$i.'" value="'.$DepName.'">'.$DepName.'</option>'."\r\n";
        }
}
echo '</select>';
echo 'Debugging';
```

It never echos `</select>` or `Debugging` to the HTML of the page.

I know that I configured `$dbc`, `$tsql`, `$params`, and `$dbcOptions` correctly because I am getting the desired results from my query.

Do I have a syntax error that my web server (WIMPServer) isn't catching?

Comment: Anything in your error logs?

Comment: Also, make sure there are no `"`, `<`, or `>` in any values of `$DepName`.

Comment: `<option row`? and you're using `$rows` `<option row` which btw, is invalid HTML.

Comment: @EdCottrell I found this in the error logs:  Use of undefined constant i. Now I have a PHP plugin to shutdown before it fill my hard drive with errors being generated by an infinite loop.

Comment: @JoelTrauger Nevermind; Mariano's answer is correct.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's a bit of debugging to see if any rows are being skipped. I will remove it in the final version.

Comment: I understand. However, I take (posted) code as being literal. Anything out of the ordinary, I question ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found it:

```
for ($i = 1; i <= $rows; $i++)
```

You forgot the dollar sign before the second `i`. It should be like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++)
```

Comment: I was just about to comment on that lol @EdCottrell however am questioning `<option row`

Comment: @EdCottrell Edited my comment above. Seems like invalid HTML.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's also true, but it seems the syntax error is what's killing the output entirely. An invalid attribute shouldn't break the output like this.

Comment: It filled my error log. 256MB and climbing...I hate infinite loops.

Answer (score 1):

you missed a dollar sign:

```
for ($i = 1; i <= $rows; $i++)
```

should be

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the error.

Instead of:

```
for ($i = 1; i <= $rows; $i++)
{
        etc
}
```

I needed to have:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++)
{
        etc
}
```

Comment: *"Discovered the error."* So did a few others before posting this. You should accept the first answer given, mainly Mariano's

Comment: I accepted it. I discovered the error after Ed asked me to check the error logs. I thought I was posting an answer before anyone else.